# How can I produce an html entity in Racket xml?

Tags: html, xml, racket

I'm trying the simple Racket web server example and I want to output the html entity for a filled square : &#9632;

But it's getting escaped automatically by the ` quasiquote mode.

How can I just use this as part of generating a chunk of html using xexpr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buried very last in section 1:

```
A symbol represents a symbolic entity. For example, 'nbsp represents &nbsp;.
```

See http://docs.racket-lang.org/xml/#%28part._.Datatypes%29

Comment: The problem is that my entity includes a hash .. so if I write '#9632 I just get an error : res.rkt:6:10: read: bad syntax `#9632 '

Comment: The next line "An valid-char? represents a numeric entity. For example, #x20 represents &#20;." is closer to what I want, but it doesn't seem to be giving me the right character

Comment: Ah .. no, that's cos it's in hex. OK. works for me now

Comment: Putting that in my source code would just seem weird. :-) There's no key for it on my keyboard.